# what can be different status while fetching the status of new unlocked package version creation

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package

I am trying to create a new package version using command
`sfdx force:package:version:create -p "test"` and need to know what can be different status of version creation I can get when I run the command `sfdx force:package:version:create:report -i subscriberPackageVersionId`. I have seen the status being **Sucess** **VerifyingMetadata** **FinalizingPackageVersion**. I need to know all the status that can be possible. I am particularly interested in the failure status messages that can be there.